# Equation of a tangent line: $f(x)=(x-4)(x^2-5)$, at $(2,2)$

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line to the graph of f at the given point:

Comment: (x+-4)(x^2+-5)? Not sure what +- means there.

Comment: Not sure if $+$ or just $-$.

Comment: I have attempted to parse this correctly. OP, if what I did is incorrect, please change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is the product rule for finding the derivatives. $\frac{d}{dx} uv = u'v + v'u$

So $u = (x-4), v = (x^2-5)$, find u' and v' and substitute into the equation to find the derivative.

Then substitute in $x = 2$ to find the slope of the line at $x = 2$, and then to find the equation of the line (since you already have the point) just substitute it into point slope form:

$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$

You should get $y - 2 = -9(x - 2)$

Comment: Thank you all so much, I greatly appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and if you are given arbitrary point on the function
 $(x_1,x_2)$, then equation of the line $\mathcal{L}_{tan}$ tangent to $f$ is given by

$$ \mathcal{L}(x) = f(x_1) + f'(x_1)(x - x_1)$$

As for your problem, you have $f$, compute $f'$ and also you are given $(x_1, x_2) = (2,2) $. Therefore, $\mathcal{L}(x) = f(2) + f'(2)(x - 2)$

To find $f'$, use your calculus tricks.